# Unit testing helper or non-interface traits in Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, traits

This question is about dealing with testing of classes which mix in non-interface traits, that is traits containing some functionality. When testing, the class functionality should be isolated from the functionality provided by the mix-in trait (which is supposedly tested separately).

I have a simple `Crawler` class, which depends on a HttpConnection and a `HttpHelpers` collection of utility functions. Let's focus on the HttpHelpers now.

**In Java**, HttpHelpers would possibly be a utility class, and would pass its singleton to Crawler as a dependency, either manually or with some IoC framework. Testing Crawler is straightforward, since the dependency is easy to mock.

**In Scala** it seems that a *helper trait* is more preferred way of composing functionality. Indeed, it is easier to use (methods automatically imported into the namespace when extending, can use `withResponse ...` instead of `httpHelper.withResponse ...`, etc.). But how does it affect testing?

This is my solution I came up with, but unfortunately it lifts some boilerplate to the testing side.

Helper trait:

```
trait HttpHelpers {
  val httpClient: HttpClient
  protected def withResponse[A](resp: HttpResponse)(fun: HttpResponse => A): A = // ...
  protected def makeGetRequest(url: String): HttpResponse = // ...
}
```

Code to test:

```
class Crawler(val httpClient: HttpClient) extends HttpHelpers {
  // ...
}
```

Test:

```
// Mock support trait
// 1) Opens up protected trait methods to public (to be able to mock their invocation)
// 2) Forwards methods to the mock object (abstract yet)
trait MockHttpHelpers extends HttpHelpers {
  val myMock: MockHttpHelpers
  override def makeGetRequest(url: String): HttpResponse = myMock.makeGetRequest(url)
}

// Create our mock using the support trait
val helpersMock = Mockito.mock(classOf[MockHttpHelpers])

// Now we can do some mocking
val mockRequest = // ...
Mockito when (helpersMock.makeGetRequest(Matchers.anyString())) thenReturn mockRequest

// Override Crawler with the mocked helper functionality
class TestCrawler extends Crawler(httpClient) with MockHttpHelpers {
  val myMock = helpersMock
}

// Now we can test
val crawler = new TestCrawler()
crawler.someMethodToTest()
```

**Question**

This approach does the work, but the need to have a mock support trait for each helper trait is a bit tedious. However I can't see any other way for this to work.

- Is this the right approach?
- If it is, could its goal be reached more efficiently (syntax magic, compiler plugin, etc)?

Any feedback is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write an Helper mock trait which should be mixed with `HttpHelpers` and override its methods with mock equivalent:

```
trait HttpHelpersMock { this: HttpHelpers =>

  //MOCK IMPLEMENTATION
  override protected def withResponse[A](resp: HttpResponse)(fun: HttpResponse => A): A = // ...

  //MOCK IMPLEMENTATION
  override protected def makeGetRequest(url: String): HttpResponse = // ...
}
```

Then, when testing crawler, you mix the mock trait at instantiation:

```
val crawlerTestee = new Crawler(x) with HttpHelpersMock
```

And the mock methods will just replace the helper methods in instance `crawlerTestee`.

**Edit:** I don't think its a good idea to test how a class interacts with an helper trait. In my opinion, you should test `Crawler` behavior and not its internal implementation detail. Implementations can change but the behavior should stay as stable as possible. The process I described above allows you to override helper methods to make them deterministic and avoid real networking, thus helping and speeding tests.

However, I believe it make sense to test the Helper itself, since it may be reused elsewhere and has a proper behavior.

Comment: This way I would loose the flexibility of using a mock framework like Mockito, specifying call counts, etc. That's why I redirected the trait methods to a mockable trait instance. So I can avoid creating a new trait with different functionality in different tests. More importantly, if I mock only one interesting method, don't have to deal with the others in the trait.

Comment: Well you could have a single full mocked trait in your test source path and use it everywhere. I don't like the idea of testing the interaction between helper methods and the helped class. For me, it's an internal implementation detail, the crawler class could be rewritten to make it independent from the helper without changing the tests themselves...

Comment: I got your point about implementation detail. Could you also lift this aspect to your answer?

Comment: Thinking about it, not mocking the helper trait in Scala would be approximately equivalent to using the Helper class as a direct static/singleton reference in Java (instead of passing it as a dependency), which is considered bad practice by some. Could you reflect on that, I'm interested in your opinion.

Comment: Most concerns I've read about singletons are about state sharing. If you helper is just a stateless "module" of methods, then they are merely implementation mechanics. So you should just focus on the behavior of other methods. However, if the trait as a state which is affected by the "helpee" object, you should worry about mocking it.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
val helpers = new HttpHelpers {
  //override or define stuff the trait needs to work properly here
}

helpers.someMethodToTest
```

Look, Ma, no intermediate traits and mocking libraries needed!

I do that all the time for my traits and I've been pretty happy with the result.

Comment: And you can even import helpers to get their members into local scope.

Comment: @Hristo: I don't really get what you mean. The helper trait would need to be mixed into the user class. How would I achieve that with your solution? (Note: I don't want to test the trait, I want to test the class using the trait)

Comment: @Daniel: If I get you right, you mean the user class does not extend the helper trait, but just import its members. But then aren't those members cut off from the outside world, not being able to mock them out? My aim is to test the user class in isolation (even from helpers).