# Play Framework & Scala: Mocking a method from with class

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, mocking

I have a method inside my Controller that I want to unit test using Spec2.

```
object MyController extends Controller with MyAuth {
  def article(id: String) = {
    authenticate {
      ......
    }
  }
}
```

`authenticate` is defined in `MyAuth`. This function gets the token if available or authenticates and gets the token. I want to mock `authenticate` while unit testing `article`. I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any pointers will be helpful.

**UPDATE: My approach so far.**
I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059859/unit-testing-helper-or-non-interface-traits-in-scala) and overrode authenticate method in MyAuth trait.

```
trait MyAuthMock {
  this: MyAuth =>

  override def authenticate ....
}
```

I also changed `MyController` to have class and companion object. Then in my test I used the controller as follows

```
new MyController with MyAuthMock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code a little bit to make it easier to test. For example:

```
class MyController extends Controller {

  def authenticate(...) // abstract method

  def article(id: String) = {
    authenticate {
        ......
    }
  }    
}

object MyController extends MyController with RealAuth
```

In your test class you would do something like:

```
val myTestController = new MyController with FakeAuth
```

Where FakeAuth is a mock.

Comment: I updated the question with the approach I went with. I am not sure what is the better approach here, yours or mine?.